# how can I load file.txt in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a folder contained several files in it 
    loc1.txt loc2.txt .... loc10.txt 
I want to use them in matlab this is my code :

```
for i=1:10
myFile =['E:\dis\locs\loc' i '.txt'];
b= importdata(myFile);
```

but it does not work and output is like this :
      `'E:\dis\locs\loc .txt'` 
is there any body help me here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `i` into characters.

```
myFile =['E:\dis\locs\loc' num2str(i) '.txt'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nemesis' answer using [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) is correct. Another possibility is to use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
myFile = sprintf('E:\dis\locs\loc%d.txt', i);
```

The interface is less intuitive if you have never seen it before but it is also very convenient when you have zero-padded numbers, like `loc0001.txt`, `loc0002.txt`, etc. In this case just replace `%d` by `%04d` like this:

```
myFile = sprintf('E:\dis\locs\loc%04d.txt', i);
```

Comment: I also thought about using `sprintf` for exactly this case. However, since in the question no padding zeros were included, I just used `num2str`.

Comment: @Nemesis, `num2str(3,'%04d')` output `0003`. The format specifier also works with `num2str` ;)